# How to get user input text in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that allows users to save form input, and later on to retrieve that saved form input and populate the form to the same saved state.

For example, I am using Jenkins jobs on a daily basis, and each time it takes me about 1 min to fill in the form input before running the job. This extension will let save the form state with some name and later on load the saved state.

My current state on this project: I am able to save and retrieve the saved data, and also to manipulate the form. Also I made a small popup that pops us when user wants to save his/her form.

My Question: How can I pass the input the user enters in the popup field to my javascript code?

My current thoughts: I have been on this for a while, did not manage to solve this. I am suspecting this API, chrome.input.ime, is the one I should use.

Comment: Use `chrome.storage`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @wOxxOm, but that is not my problem.
I need to get the users input - after getting the input I know how to handle it.

Comment: The idea is that you can use chrome.storage to read/write the values in any "javascript code". It's unclear what specifically the problem is as your question lacks an [MCVE](/help/mcve).